# Error using malloc for multiple 2D arrays

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I have the following code segment:

```
        int  i;

        double** endpt1 = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(MAXVAR+1));
        for (i=0; i<(MAXVAR+1); i++)
          endpt1[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*MAXFILES);

-->     double** endpt2 = (double**)malloc(sizeof(double*)*(MAXVAR+1));
        for (i=0; i<(MAXVAR+1); i++)
          endpt2[i] = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*MAXFILES);
```

I get the following error when compiling in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7:

error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'type'

error C2065: 'endpt2': undeclared identifier

error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

The error points to the line with the arrow.  I only get this if I am trying to allocate more than one 2D array in a given file.  The error always occurs at the start of the second definition.  Any ideas as to why I'm getting this compiler error.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

In C (C89, anyway), variables are declared at the top of a function.  Use:

```
int i;
double **endpt1;
double **endpt2;
endpt1 = malloc(sizeof(double*)*(MAXVAR+1));
for (i=0; i<(MAXVAR+1); i++)
    endpt1[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAXFILES);

endpt2 = malloc(sizeof(double*)*(MAXVAR+1));
for (i=0; i<(MAXVAR+1); i++)
    endpt2[i] = malloc(sizeof(double)*MAXFILES);
```

Also, no need to cast the `malloc` in C.